# jquery load more function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a function of load more using jquery and placed in an external file named main.js here is what I have created

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#comment_list li").size();
    x=2;
    $('#comment_list li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#comment_list li:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 2 : x-5;
        $('#comment_list li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });
});
```

Although it is working fine but with 1 only as the data of comments is more then 1 like

```
<ul class="comment_response" id="comment_list">
   <li></li>
</ul>

<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>

<ul class="comment_response" id="comment_list">
   <li></li>
</ul>

<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
```

The first one is working but it is not working with second one can anyone help me out why this is happening ?

Comment: Element `id`s must be unique.

Comment: ids are mising quote before >

Comment: so if i place id like this id="comment_list<?php echo $cid; ?>" how can i pass this to main.js jquery function  ?

Comment: Generally, you can use `this` in your click handler, then use traversal functions to get to the elements you want to modify.

Comment: little bit weak with jquery can you modify in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not have more than one element with one id. change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $(".comment_list li").length;
    x=2;
    $(this).previous().find('li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('.loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $(this).previous().find('li:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
    $('.showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 2 : x-5;
        $(this).previous().find('li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="comment_response comment_list>
   <li></li>
</ul>

<div class="loadMore">Load more</div>

<ul class="comment_response comment_list>
   <li></li>
</ul>

<div class="loadMore">Load more</div>
```

Comment: not working when i click second it load more for the first one

Comment: The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and removed from 3.0. Use the .length property instead. source: https://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: @dragoeco, I changed the code, thanks. Actually I use length and I was'nt aware of `size()` function's existence. I had just copied the OP's code and made changes to it. ;)